# How to draw and format a line?

Tags: vba, format, powerpoint, drawing

I am trying to draw a line in a PowerPoint presentation. I cannot get the desired combinations of colour, weight, zorder and to name it.

I have two ways to draw a line.

The first:

```
Set oLine = MyDocument.Shapes.AddLine(MyShape.Left + MyShape.Width, MyShape.Top + (MyShape.Height * 0.5) - 5, MyDocument.Shapes(lineName).Left, MyDocument.Shapes(lineName).Top + (0.5 * MyDocument.Shapes(lineName).Height)).Line
            
With oLine
    .ZOrder (msoSendToBack)
    .Line.Weight = 7
    .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    .Name = "Line"
End With
```

With this only the zorder works. The colour of the line is a shade of blue (which I believe was used earlier in the PowerPoint).

The second:

```
With MyDocument.Shapes.AddLine(MyShape.Left + MyShape.Width, MyShape.Top + (MyShape.Height * 0.5), MyDocument.Shapes(lineName).Left, MyDocument.Shapes(lineName).Top + (0.5 * MyDocument.Shapes(lineName).Height)).Line
    .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    .Weight = 5
End With
```

This gives the desired colour and weight, but I cannot find a way to zorder the shape nor name it.

How can I achieve all of my desired combinations?

Comment: When posting code, please post a sample that actually runs. Don't expect us to reconstruct the macro that this is excerpted from.

Comment: Apologies if this caused offence. I shall remember to do this next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lines don't use a fill, only 2D shapes.

It's easier to find errors if you break long commands (like the one starting with Set oLine) into smaller chunks until you get it working. You omitted information about the MyShape from which you're getting positions, but here is a revised version of your code that runs:

```
Sub FormatLine()
    Dim oLine As Shape
    Set oLine = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.AddLine(BeginX:=10, BeginY:=10, EndX:=40, EndY:=40)
            
    With oLine
        .ZOrder (msoSendToBack)
        .Line.Weight = 7
        .Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        .Name = "Line3"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: John Korchok - thank you so much - the code now works! I spent quite a few hours trying to get this functioning (so I am relieved!) The reason why it now works is because my code had an .Line on the end of the AddLine function. I did this because that was what Microsoft had in their example using.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.shapes.addline (At the time I thought the .Line was  required syntax to the create a new line command and not referring to the shapes .Line properties!) I hope that makes sense and thank you!

Comment: Adding "Set oLine =" changes the syntax so that .Line at the end doesn't work. Plus Microsoft's examples have many mistakes, they're really just a starting point.